# New monitor has possible hardware fault

Tags: troubleshooting, visual-artifacts

There are vertical green dotted lines on the screen of my new monitor, they happen with HDMI, DP or no wires in.

They disappear for a while when I fiddle with the displayport

Does anyone know:

A) What this issue is roughly, so It is easier to get a refund

B) Whether this issue is easily fixable (without voiding warranty)

Answer (score 1):

(A) Just describe the issue as you have done here. Customers are not expected to troubleshoot . It is not working correctly.

(B) Not likely as as you would have to open the monitor to determine the faulty part.

Just return for warranty replacement.

I assume you tried another connection cable if you have one to try.